# Why I cannot map modelMapper to Commercetools classes?

Tags: modelmapper, commercetools

I recently work with ModelMapper and I have a question. I'm trying to map my CustomerRequest to Commercetools CustomerDraftDsl class.

```
@Component
public class CreateCustomerCommandMapper extends PropertyMap<CustomerRequest, CustomerDraftDsl> {


    protected void configure() {
        map().withFirstName(source.getFirstName());
    }
```

My method:

```
public void createCustomer(CustomerRequest customer) {
        CustomerDraftDsl draft = mapper.addMappings(new CreateCustomerCommandMapper()).map(customer);
        System.out.println(draft);
        executeRequestBlocking(CustomerCreateCommand.of(draft));
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Why I cannot map my request to commerce tools classes?

I've got this response:

```
ModelMapper configuration errors:

1) Failed to configure mappings
```

Answer (score 0):

Email and password are required for create customer. Where is the code to set them?

Best Regards
Brian